# Progressbar windows phone 8 separate thread

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-8, progress-bar, dispatcher

Is it possible to run a progressbar in windows phone 8 on a separate thread, or using the Dispatcher class?

thanx

Comment: Pls provide us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put ur progress bar in `App.xaml`

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="ProgressBar_Loaded" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

& then put this c# code into ur `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        // progress bar
        public ProgressBar m_progressBar;
        // some code......


        private void ProgressBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_progressBar = (ProgressBar)sender;
        }
    }
```

define a separate method in a `class`

```
public static Class RestMethods
{
   public static void ShowProgress(bool show)
        {
            if (show)
                ((App)Application.Current).m_progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                ((App)Application.Current).m_progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
}
```

now u have separate method to show or hide the progress bar

call it in a dispature, so it wont freez ur `UI`--->

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { RestMethods.ShowProgress(true); });    // to show
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { RestMethods.ShowProgress(false); });    // to hide
```

Comment: @Ashok, what is the reason to put ProgressBar to App.xaml? To have an access to ProgressBar from everywhere in app? Anyway Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { RestMethods.ShowProgress(true); });  will be called in UI thread, Dispatcher will marshal a call to UI thread. Moreover ProgressBar in WP8 doesn't freeze UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

UI controls in WindowsPhone can be updated just from UI thread and it is not possible to update `ProgressBar` from separate (not UI) thread. `Dispatcher` just will marshal a call from working thread to UI thread.